# Added fields to table in the AOT are not synchronized

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I add some fields in AOT to a table. Usually when I save this changes, I find the added fields in the database table too, but not this time.

I have already tried to compile and save again and also start the synchronization with right click on the table -> Synchronize.

But I didn't find the added fields in the database table.

Have anybody some solutions for me?

[Screenshot of AOT and Properties of the fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVU53.png)

Comment: Just to make sure, the fields are shown in the AOT, but are not shown in SQL Management Studio?

Comment: yes this is the current situation. The fields are shown in AOT but not in SQL Management Studio.

Comment: Try deleting and adding the fields again. If that does not help, try a full synchronisation on the whole data dictionary.

Comment: i have already tried a full synchronisation. I will try deleting and adding again.

Comment: Deleting and adding the fields again did not work

Comment: Curious, must be some special fields ;) Could you post a screenshot of the table in the AOT with the properties of one of the fields? Maybe something jumps out to me. Other than that try the usual suspects: AOS restart, compile, CIL compile, maybe delete .auc files. You could also try to add the fields in another system to see if the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: i add the screenshot of the 3 types of fields to the question above. ok i will try your suggestions

Comment: AOS restart, compile, full CIL compile and deleting .auc files didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers, but the solution, that worked for me was:

I restore the database with a backup file (possible, because it's an development system) and then i make my changes again.

I don't know why, but now i can see my added fields.

Thank you all again.

Comment: Perhaps the AOS account did not have sufficient permissions in the old database?  Ref section "Create a Microsoft Dynamics AX database manually" of the [AX 2012 Installation Guide](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12687).  I'm sure a warning would have appeared, however.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen that happen in 2012 and especially not with fields that have don't use an extended data type.

In previous versions you could disable a configuration or security key and then tables/fields were not synchronized to the database table but 2012 always syncs.

Things you could check though

- Make really really sure you are connected to the right database (verify the server and database name from `System Administration > inquiries > database > database information`)
- Check the `SQLDICTIONARY` table in SQL, it contains a table and field id, you should be able to find your table and fields there. If they aren't the dictionary and the AOT might be out of sync
- Use the `Check/Synchronize` button from the `SQL Administration` form under `System administration > periodic > Database > SQL Administration`

Comment: i have checked the points you mentioned, but i noticed nothing wrong.